# Yii2: create relation via table how to?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I can get the results using this query in mysql.

```sql
SELECT    group_concat(im.instrument_name) AS instrument 
FROM      ot_note otn 
LEFT JOIN ot_instrument_entry oie ON otn.id=oie.ot_note_id
LEFT JOIN instrument_master im    ON oie.instrument_name=im.id
GROUP BY  otn.id
```

Now I have a model `OTNote`, `InstrumentMaster` and `OTInstrumentEntry`.

I have tried to use a relation using via table, but it looks like I am missing something.

I have tried to create the relation like this, but it is throwing error;

```
public function getInstrumentMaster()
{
    return $this
       ->hasMany(OtInstrumentEntry::className(), ['ot_note_id' => 'id'])
       ->viaTable('instrument_master', ['id'=>'instrument_name']);
}
```

How can I can create a relation so I can access the column instrument_master.instrument_name column which is related to ot_instrument_entry?

Comment: Can you post what error is it creating?. If possible try checking with the yii debugger about the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ot_instrument_entry` is the linking table. In class `OTNote` you should have:

```
// class OTNote

public function getInstrumentMaster()
{
    return $this
       ->hasMany(InstrumentMaster::className(), ['id' => 'instrument_name'])
       ->viaTable('ot_instrument_entry', ['ot_note_id' => 'id']);
}
```

In class `InstrumentMaster` you may want to have this for vice versa access:

```
// class InstrumentMaster

public function getOTNotes()
{
    return $this
       ->hasMany(OTNote::className(), ['id' => 'ot_note_id'])
       ->viaTable('ot_instrument_entry', ['instrument_name' => 'id']);
}
```

Details can be found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relations-via-a-junction-table).

Comment: OK not exactly - I have to modify the query like `public function getInstrumentMaster()
    {
    return $this
       ->hasMany(InstrumentMaster::className(), ['id' => 'instrument_name'])
       ->viaTable('ot_instrument_entry', ['ot_note_id' => 'id']);
    }`

Comment: @Pawan I thought it... Thanks! I corrected my answer.